# Access settings not transfered in change set of site

Tags: deployment, force.com-sites, change-set, guest-user, access

I created a site on a sandbox. Set all Guest access and settings for the profile.

The qa process is that I publish this to a 2nd sandbox.

I can't upload the entire site, so I created the site on the new sandbox.

How do I publish the 'Public Access Settings' to the new Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
Site > select site > Public Access Settings
```

Then you can set your access as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer the question. I don't want to redo the entire access settings. This is prone to errors.

Comment: I think is the only method to do that

Comment: Unfortunately not everything can be deployed with Change Sets or even using the API based methods like the deployment tool, so this may be a case where you do have to manually repeat the steps.